# Is my recursive solution for string concatenation right?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Problem: Given three strings A, B and C. Write a function that checks whether C is an interleaving of A and B. C is said to be interleaving A and B, if it contains all characters of A and B and order of all characters in individual strings is preserved.
Example:
A = "AB",  B = "CD", C = CDAB
In this case C is concatenated string of A and B.

I have written below code in C. Wanted to know if i am missing any test cases or if this can be improved.
Logic is just to check each characters of C with A and B and the increment the index using recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_concatenated(char *g1, char *g2, int m, int n, int l, char *target, int i, int j, int k)
{
    if (m+n > l)
        return 0;
    if (k == l)
        return 1;
    /* for handling duplicated characters in A and B */
    if ((i < m ) && g1[i] == target[k] && (j < n) && g2[j] == target[k]) {
        return is_concatenated(g1, g2, m, n, l, target, i+1, j, k+1) || is_concatenated(g1, g2, m, n, l, target, i, j+1, k+1);
    }

    if ((i < m ) && g1[i] == target[k]) {
        return is_concatenated(g1, g2, m, n, l, target, i+1, j, k+1);
    }
    if ((j < n) && g2[j] == target[k]) {
        return is_concatenated(g1, g2, m, n, l, target, i, j+1, k+1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char *g1 = "ABCD";
    char *g2 = "BCDX";
    char target[] = {"ABBCDXBCD"};
    printf("%d\n", is_concatenated(g1, g2, strlen(g1), strlen(g2), strlen(target), target, 0, 0, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct but the problem is that your worst-case complexity is `2^{min(m, n)}`. Consider the case when you have:

```
g1 = 1111111111111111111111111111112
g2 = 1111111111111111111111111111113
target = 11111111111111111111111111111131111111111111111111111111111112
```

You, then, might be interested in more efficient solution. There is a `O(nm)` solution using dynamic programming. The idea is to use an array `f[i][j]`for which `f[i][j] = 1` if and only if `target[0...i+j-1]` is an interleaving of `g1[0...i-1]` and `g2[0...j-1]`. [Reference](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-string-is-an-interleaving-of-two-other-given-strings-set-2/)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct so far. [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17909/print-all-interleavings-of-two-given-strings) is a good discussion on this problem. I like the mention of the std::next_permutation(). Perhaps you could use the std library function to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question statement, i suppose your code should print 1 for the given input. Correct me if i am wrong.

If the output should be 0, your logic and code is perfectly fine.

But if the output should be 1, i am worried that your code returns wrong output for the given input. This is because your variable ***k*** will never reach the target length ***l*** for the given case.

You can make it work by incrementing ***k*** when characters in ***g1***, ***g2*** doesnt match ***k*** th character in ***target*** string. And also check for the lengths of the strings ***g1*** and ***g2*** in the boundary condition.

Hope this makes your code give correct output.

Comment: @noman-  How come it is 0! Aren't extra characters other than those in the 2 strings allowed in the target string?

Comment: Nope. Check the example in my question. It should just be in sequence with no extra characters.

Comment: Then it isn't an answer

Comment: @washington - i agree. I just thought of providing my inputs.